# How to distinguish FIDO2 devices

Tags: webauthn

I want to distinguish the authentication device in webauthn.

I want to know if that is possible and how I can do it if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no simple WebAuthn API function you can call to say, "give me the name of available authenticators". The WebAuthn API was intentionally designed to make it difficult to determine specific makes and models of authenticators [in the name of greater user privacy](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-privacy-considerations).

The only reliable way to determine an authenticator's make and model is to [request direct attestation during registration](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dom-publickeycredentialcreationoptions-attestation), and then cross-reference the `aaguid` you get back with a list you've collected and maintain yourself, or through something like the [Fido Alliance Metadata Service](https://fidoalliance.org/metadata/).

> Note: If you don't request `"direct"` attestation you're likely [to get back an obscured `aaguid`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-createCredential):
> [image]

[For **platform authenticators** specifically](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dom-authenticatorselectioncriteria-authenticatorattachment) you can try creating "heuristics", based on things like browser screen dimensions and User Agent analysis, that try to reliably determine whether system-level authenticators like Touch ID or Windows Hello are available. After a user successfully registers a credential with your site you'd want to store the results of your heuristics analysis with the credential to provide UX hints later during authentication (e.g. "we determined the user registered a Windows Hello credential, so show them 'Enter your Hello PIN to continue' UI during authentication.")

Comment: Also note that if going down the path of attestation, e.g. Chrome requires your site to keep this list up to date or risk losing access to the WebAuthn API: https://www.chromium.org/security-keys "public websites that restrict the set of allowed Security Keys should do so based on articulable, technical considerations. They should regularly update their set of trusted attestation roots that meet their policies [...] If Chrome becomes aware that websites are not meeting these expectations, we may withdraw Security Key privileges from those sites."

Comment: Worth noting they there is a WebAuthn API to check for the presence of a platform (i.e. built in) authenticator which can be useful in certain circumstances. There’s also the option of storing details of registered authenticators in a persistent cookie but this can’t be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to fetch the details on FIDO devices from the FIDO Metadata Service. However, it's possible that it'll not have entries for all the devices.

There's a community curated list (json file) which is maintained by dev community which we can use easily to lookup the specific device from their AAGUID. (It only maintains the name and icons of the device though)

1. Set [`attestation=direct`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#enum-attestation-convey) option when creating a new Credential
2. This will give the attestation-statement (AAGUID) as generated by the Authenticator device
3. Use this AAGUID to search from the [list](https://github.com/passkeydeveloper/passkey-authenticator-aaguids/blob/main/combined_aaguid.json) to find more information on the device

   - The above list is a combination of community curated and those provided by [FIDO Metadata service](https://fidoalliance.org/metadata/)

A sample entry in the file is like below which can be searched using the AAGUID:

```json
    "6028b017-b1d4-4c02-b4b3-afcdafc96bb2": {
        "name": "Windows Hello",
        "icon_dark": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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",
        "icon_light": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
    },
    "dd4ec289-e01d-41c9-bb89-70fa845d4bf2": {
        "name": "iCloud Keychain (Managed)",
        "icon_dark": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTYgMjU2IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIj48cGF0aCBkPSJtMjE3LjM2LDkwLjY5Yy0xNS41OCw5LjU0LTI1LjE3LDI2LjQxLTI1LjM4LDQ0LjY4LjA2LDIwLjY3LDEyLjQzLDM5LjMyLDMxLjQ2LDQ3LjQxLTMuNjcsMTEuODQtOS4xLDIzLjA2LTE2LjExLDMzLjI4LTEwLjAzLDE0LjQ0LTIwLjUyLDI4Ljg3LTM2LjQ3LDI4Ljg3cy0yMC4wNi05LjI3LTM4LjQ1LTkuMjctMjQuMzIsOS41Ny0zOC45LDkuNTctMjQuNzctMTMuMzctMzYuNDctMjkuNzljLTE1LjQ2LTIyLjk5LTIzLjk1LTQ5Ljk2LTI0LjQ3LTc3LjY2LDAtNDUuNTksMjkuNjMtNjkuNzUsNTguODEtNjkuNzUsMTUuNSwwLDI4LjQyLDEwLjE4LDM4LjE1LDEwLjE4czIzLjcxLTEwLjc5LDQxLjM0LTEwLjc5YzE4LjQxLS40NywzNS44NCw4LjI0LDQ2LjUsMjMuMjVabS01NC44Ni00Mi41NWM3Ljc3LTkuMTQsMTIuMTctMjAuNjcsMTIuNDYtMzIuNjcuMDEtMS41OC0uMTQtMy4xNi0uNDYtNC43MS0xMy4zNSwxLjMtMjUuNjksNy42Ny0zNC41LDE3Ljc4LTcuODUsOC43OC0xMi40MSwyMC0xMi45MiwzMS43NiwwLDEuNDMuMTYsMi44Ni40Niw0LjI2LDEuMDUuMiwyLjEyLjMsMy4xOS4zLDEyLjQzLS45OSwyMy45MS03LjA0LDMxLjc2LTE2LjczWiIgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==",
        "icon_light": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTYgMjU2IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIj48cGF0aCBkPSJtMjE3LjM2LDkwLjY5Yy0xNS41OCw5LjU0LTI1LjE3LDI2LjQxLTI1LjM4LDQ0LjY4LjA2LDIwLjY3LDEyLjQzLDM5LjMyLDMxLjQ2LDQ3LjQxLTMuNjcsMTEuODQtOS4xLDIzLjA2LTE2LjExLDMzLjI4LTEwLjAzLDE0LjQ0LTIwLjUyLDI4Ljg3LTM2LjQ3LDI4Ljg3cy0yMC4wNi05LjI3LTM4LjQ1LTkuMjctMjQuMzIsOS41Ny0zOC45LDkuNTctMjQuNzctMTMuMzctMzYuNDctMjkuNzljLTE1LjQ2LTIyLjk5LTIzLjk1LTQ5Ljk2LTI0LjQ3LTc3LjY2LDAtNDUuNTksMjkuNjMtNjkuNzUsNTguODEtNjkuNzUsMTUuNSwwLDI4LjQyLDEwLjE4LDM4LjE1LDEwLjE4czIzLjcxLTEwLjc5LDQxLjM0LTEwLjc5YzE4LjQxLS40NywzNS44NCw4LjI0LDQ2LjUsMjMuMjVabS01NC44Ni00Mi41NWM3Ljc3LTkuMTQsMTIuMTctMjAuNjcsMTIuNDYtMzIuNjcuMDEtMS41OC0uMTQtMy4xNi0uNDYtNC43MS0xMy4zNSwxLjMtMjUuNjksNy42Ny0zNC41LDE3Ljc4LTcuODUsOC43OC0xMi40MSwyMC0xMi45MiwzMS43NiwwLDEuNDMuMTYsMi44Ni40Niw0LjI2LDEuMDUuMiwyLjEyLjMsMy4xOS4zLDEyLjQzLS45OSwyMy45MS03LjA0LDMxLjc2LTE2LjczWiIgZmlsbD0iIzAwMCIvPjwvc3ZnPg=="
    },
```